# Custom domain for heroku not working after user confirms email using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku, devise

I'm making a web app using Angular on frontend and Rails on backend.
I'm using Namecheap to host my domain and let's say my custom domain is `www.coolapp.com`.
In Heroku, I configure custom domain so `coolapp.herokuapp.com` gets redirected to `www.coolapp.com`.

Custom domain works all fine except one edge case. When user clicks a link to confirm their email, they are being redirected to heroku URL not custom domain URL. They are supposed to be redirected to `www.coolapp.com/sign_in` but instead they are redirected to `coolapp.herokuapp.com/sign_in`. Besides this edge case, custom domain works fine.

Would appreciate any help.